# Flutter Mobile App - Getting null check runtime error on real device, but not on simulator

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement a screen where a user would upload photos to add to their profile. I am using a StreamBuilder to do this. For some reason, on my simulator the screen works perfectly fine and loads all widgets normally, however when I run this specific screen on my physical device I have a runtime error due to a null check... Can someone help me find out why this is happening?

Something I also noticed is that on my physical device, inside of the Builder of StreamBuilder, the code falls to the else statement where I have a comment (// TODO() : implement connection state error check)... however on the simulator it executes the top level code block. That's why I have some duplicate code right now.

Basically, Im checking Firebase storage for the user's photos, if they don't have any I will pass an empty string to symbolize that

Code:

````
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:locusu/classes/firebase_methods.dart';
import 'package:locusu/classes/jcu_colors.dart';
import 'package:locusu/screens/dorm_pref.dart';
import 'package:locusu/widgets/picture_container.dart';

class OnboardPhotos extends StatefulWidget {
  const OnboardPhotos({super.key});

  @override
  State<OnboardPhotos> createState() => OnboardPhotosState();
}

class OnboardPhotosState extends State<OnboardPhotos> {

  late Stream<List<String>> streamData = FirebaseMethods().getProfilePhotos();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.topRight,
              colors: [
                 JcuColors().gradientColor1,
                 JcuColors().gradientColor2,
              ]
            ),
          ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(height: 100),
                      
                      const Center(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.photo_album_outlined,
                          size: 75,
                          ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                       Center(
                            child: Text(
                                "Add some photos to your profile",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 25,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

                          const SizedBox(height: 30),

                          StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
                          stream: streamData,
                          initialData: const [""],
                          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot) {
                          List<String> photos = snapshot.data!;
                          print(snapshot.data![0] == "");
                          print(snapshot.hasData);
                          if(snapshot.hasData) {
                            return Column(
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                    children: [
                                      PictureContainer(photoURL: snapshot.data![0] == "" ? "" : photos[0]),
                                      PictureContainer(photoURL: snapshot.data![0] == "" ? "" : photos[1]),
                                      PictureContainer(photoURL: snapshot.data![0] == "" ? "" : photos[2]),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 15),

                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                    children: [
                                      PictureContainer(photoURL: snapshot.data![0] == "" ? "" : photos[3]),
                                      PictureContainer(photoURL: snapshot.data![0] == "" ? "" : photos[4]),
                                      PictureContainer(photoURL: snapshot.data![0] == "" ? "" : photos[5]),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                              ],
                            );
                          }
                          else if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                          ConnectionState.none) {
                          return Center(
                              child: Text(
                                  "No network connection, try again later.",
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                  ),
                                )
                              );
                         }
                         else {
                          // TODO() : implement connection state error check
                          return Column(
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                    children: [
                                      PictureContainer(photoURL: snapshot.data![0] == "" ? "" : photos[0]),
                                      PictureContainer(photoURL: snapshot.data![0] == "" ? "" : photos[1]),
                                      PictureContainer(photoURL: snapshot.data![0] == "" ? "" : photos[2]),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 15),

                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                    children: [
                                      PictureContainer(photoURL: snapshot.data![0] == "" ? "" : photos[3]),
                                      PictureContainer(photoURL: snapshot.data![0] == "" ? "" : photos[4]),
                                      PictureContainer(photoURL: snapshot.data![0] == "" ? "" : photos[5]),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                              ],
                            );
                         }
              
                      }
                    ),

                    const SizedBox(height: 50),

                      Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 35.0),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const DormPreference()));
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'Continue',
                                style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 22,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    ],
                ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: I assume the issue is coming from `PictureContainer(photoURL: snapshot.data![0] == "" ? "" : photos[1]),` instead of adding  null assert`!`, try to do a null check first

`PictureContainer(photoURL: snapshot.data?[1]??"",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Darshan Kachhadiya and @Yeasin Sheikh I was able to figure out the problem. Here's the final code:

````
                          stream: streamData,
                          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot) {
                            //print(snapshot.data);
                            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                              // While waiting for data to arrive, you can show a loading indicator.
                              return CircularProgressIndicator();
                            
                            } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null || snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
                              // If there is no data available, show a message indicating no photos are present.
                              return Column(
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                    children: [
                                      PictureContainer(photoURL: ""),
                                      PictureContainer(photoURL: ""),
                                      PictureContainer(photoURL: ""),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 15),
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                    children: [
                                      PictureContainer(photoURL: ""),
                                      PictureContainer(photoURL: ""),
                                      PictureContainer(photoURL: ""),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              );
                            } else {
                              print("Here");
                              // Data is available, show the photos using the `PictureContainer` widget.
                              List<String> photos = snapshot.data!;
                              int numPhotos = photos.length;
                              print(numPhotos);
                              return Column(
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                    children: [
                                      numPhotos > 0 ? PictureContainer(photoURL: photos[0]) : PictureContainer(photoURL: ""),
                                      numPhotos > 1 ? PictureContainer(photoURL: photos[1]) : PictureContainer(photoURL: ""),
                                      numPhotos > 2 ? PictureContainer(photoURL: photos[2]) : PictureContainer(photoURL: ""),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 15),
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                    children: [
                                      numPhotos > 3 ? PictureContainer(photoURL: photos[3]) : PictureContainer(photoURL: ""),
                                      numPhotos > 4 ? PictureContainer(photoURL: photos[4]) : PictureContainer(photoURL: ""),
                                      numPhotos > 5 ? PictureContainer(photoURL: photos[5]) : PictureContainer(photoURL: ""),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              );
                            }
                          },
                        ),```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code,some change in code:

```
StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
  stream: streamData,
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      // While waiting for data to arrive, you can show a loading indicator.
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      // If there's an error with the stream, display an error message.
      return Center(
        child: Text(
          "Error loading photos. Please try again later.",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 18,
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null || snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
      // If there is no data available, show a message indicating no photos are present.
      return Center(
        child: Text(
          "No photos available. Add some photos to your profile.",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 18,
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      // Data is available, show the photos using the `PictureContainer` widget.
      List<String> photos = snapshot.data!;
      return Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              PictureContainer(photoURL: photos[0]),
              PictureContainer(photoURL: photos[1]),
              PictureContainer(photoURL: photos[2]),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 15),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              PictureContainer(photoURL: photos[3]),
              PictureContainer(photoURL: photos[4]),
              PictureContainer(photoURL: photos[5]),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  },
),
```

Comment: This definitely is better than what I have. However, I have 6 of these containers, and basically I want users to be able to tap them and upload images and have them load in one by one, but it isn't seeming to work. Gonna look into it more

Comment: can you provide me code and image screen shot @antonr00ls

Comment: I was able to fix it

Comment: Posted code above